# Oracle: Replacing non-numeric chars in a string

Tags: oracle11g, replace

I have a field in my database where users have saved free-form telephone numbers. As a result, the data has all sorts of different formatting:

- (area) nnn-nnnn
- area-nnn-nnnn
- area.nnn.nnnn
- etc

I would like to strip out all the non-numeric characters and just store the digits, but I can't find a simple way to do this. Is it possible without using one REPLACE for each char?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302) since Oracle 10:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('+34 (947) 123 456 ext. 2013', '[^0-9]+', '')
FROM DUAL
```

This example returns `349471234562013`.

Alternative syntaxes include:

- POSIX character classes:

  ```
  '[^[:digit:]]+'
  ```
- Perl-influenced extensions (since Oracle 11):

  ```
  '\D+'
  ```

Comment: This answer saved my day. Though through a bit of googling I found out that you can replace `'[^0-9]+'` with `'[^[:digit:]]+'`. :)

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin - That's a POSIX character class. If I recall correctly, they weren't supported in earlier versions, but should work fine with recent releases.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Alvaro. I got it from here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/2404, tested it in my 11g database, and posted my comment above. I guess during the process I kinda forgot to notice which version this is supported. :)

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin Please disregard the part about Oracle version. I was confused with [PERL-Influenced Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDDGICJ) such as `\d`. POSIX syntax was available from the beginning (i.e., 10g).

Answer (score 15):

For older versions of Oracle that don't support regular expressions:

```
select translate (phone_no,'0'||translate (phone_no,'x0123456789','x'),'0')
from mytable;
```

The inner `translate` gets all the non-digit characters from the phone number, and the outer `translate` then removes them from the phone number.

Comment: really coll way! I suppose hat regexp take more CPU power instead of translate