# Oracle To_Char function How to handle if it's already a string

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, to-char

Scenario: I am calling a function that returns a field that the user enters in. The field usually returns a number like '120000' which I then use to_char to convert into '120,000'.

Problem: Some users enter in values such as '120,000' which gives me an error when trying to use to_char. Also the function will return a space ' ' if no value is found. I tried something with to_number earlier and it has a problem with the ' ' I believe.

Question: What would be the best way to handle this problem? Case statement checking for the ','? Using to_number then to_char?

Note: I can hack a solution together I'm just wondering what the best way to handle this is.

Comment: Strip the commas out and then use `to_char` as above.  Either that or tell the user to only enter digits.

Comment: The best way would be to prevent the users from entering numbers with commas in the first place. If you can't control that, then Jack's on the money - just strip the commas out with `REPLACE(field, ',', '')`

Comment: I would force user to enter a number, not a formatted number (120,000).  Also, some places use . instead of , so strip out commas won't always work.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have that control. This is coming from a program called Amanda (by CSDC). It's an info code that anything can be entered into. I will use REPLACE thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using REPLACE you should use the more powerful `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/REGEXP_REPLACE

You can then remove any non-numeric character from the string before then formatting it however you like.

In your case it would be something like:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(<your field>, '[^0-9]+', '');
```

This replaces all non-numeric characters with null effectively removing them from the string.

See this answer too:
[Oracle: Replacing non-numeric chars in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968178/oracle-replacing-non-numeric-chars-in-a-string)

Comment: What happens if the "LINKS" in the answers are broken in the future? :) I quote yourself from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060917/using-nested-tables-in-java/12061531#comment16109755_12061531)

Comment: @Annjawn, as you have appeared to trawl my previous answers for those containing links I can only assume you have taken my comment from the answer you have linked to in a way it wasn't intended. It was not designed to cause you offence. FWIW, I believe this answer stands, even if the link ever breaks as it contains both information as well as a link. Do you not agree?

Comment: I do. But the links can break. Anytime, without any reason. But that doesn't mean we would stop using them.

Comment: Hence I'd advocate both links and information. It gives a more persistent and helpful answer. As you can see, I happily use links and hope others do too but bear in mind they can and do break over time.