# Character to number conversion error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

```
declare
   l_tot number := 0;

begin
   for i in 1..apex_application.g_f08.count loop
      l_tot := l_tot + nvl(to_number(apex_application.g_f08(i)),0);
   end loop;

 if l_tot = nvl(to_number(:P21_TOTAL_PRICE),0) then
      return true;
   else
      return false;
   end if;
end;
```

Got below error with above code

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

Error occurred with `:P21_TOTAL_PRICE`. What is the wrong ? How can i correct this ?

Comment: do you have commas or spaces in the price field?

Comment: @Sathya Yes. Value in `:P21_TOTAL_PRICE` like `5,500.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error rises because the number that you're representing is actually a character string involving commas etc. When you put a to_number to that, Oracle cannot replace the commas.

You might want to use [replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) function to strip off the commas

Change

```
if l_tot = nvl(to_number(:P21_TOTAL_PRICE),0) then
```

to

```
if l_tot = nvl(to_number(replace(:P21_TOTAL_PRICE,',','')),0) then
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using REPLACE you should use the more powerful REGEXP_REPLACE function. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/REGEXP_REPLACE

You can then remove any non-numeric character from the string before then using the `TO_NUMBER` function.

In your case it would be something like:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(:P21_TOTAL_PRICE, '[^0-9]+', '');
```

See my answer to almost the exact same question here: [Oracle To_Char function How to handle if it's already a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069278/oracle-to-char-function-how-to-handle-if-its-already-a-string/9071501#9071501)