# using nested_tables in java

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

How do I receive a nested table in java from pl/sql procedure's OUT parameter? Here is my example code.

```
Connection connection = utilities.getConnectionToDb();
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call procedure_name(?,?)}");
callableStatement.setLong(1, 23456);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY);
callableStatement.executeQuery();
```

But when I try executing it I get the error
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'procedure_name'

I am sure that the number of arguments are correct.

Comment: It says "wrong number or types of argument to _call_..." I don't know any Java but I'd guess you're _calling_ the procedure incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8908169959941

I am quoting this from the website above-

```
SQL> create or replace type numArray as table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type dateArray as table of date;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type strArray as table of varchar2(255);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace package demo_passing_pkg
  2  as
  3      procedure pass( p_in in numArray, p_out out numArray )
  4      as language java
  5      name 'demo_passing_pkg.pass_num_array( oracle.sql.ARRAY,
  6                                             oracle.sql.ARRAY[] )';
  7
  8      procedure pass( p_in in dateArray, p_out out dateArray )
  9      as language java
 10      name 'demo_passing_pkg.pass_date_array( oracle.sql.ARRAY,
 11                                              oracle.sql.ARRAY[] )';
 12
 13
 14      procedure pass( p_in in strArray, p_out out strArray )
 15      as language java
 16      name 'demo_passing_pkg.pass_str_array( oracle.sql.ARRAY,
 17                                             oracle.sql.ARRAY[] )';
 18  end;
 19  /

Package created.

SQL> set define off
SQL>
SQL> create or replace and compile
  2  java source named "demo_passing_pkg"
  3  as
  4  import java.io.*;
  5  import java.sql.*;
  6  import java.math.*;
  7  import oracle.sql.*;
  8  import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
  9
 10  public class demo_passing_pkg extends Object
 11  {
 12
 13  private static void show_array_info( oracle.sql.ARRAY p_in )
 14  throws SQLException
 15  {
 16      System.out.println( "Array is of type      " +
 17                           p_in.getSQLTypeName() );
 18      System.out.println( "Array is of type code " +
 19                           p_in.getBaseType() );
 20      System.out.println( "Array is of length    " +
 21                           p_in.length() );
 22  }
 23
 24  public static void pass_num_array( oracle.sql.ARRAY p_in,
 25                                     oracle.sql.ARRAY[] p_out )
 26  throws SQLException
 27  {
 28      show_array_info( p_in );
 29      java.math.BigDecimal[] values = (BigDecimal[])p_in.getArray();
 30
 31      for( int i = 0; i < p_in.length(); i++ )
 32          System.out.println( "p_in["+i+"] = " + values[i].toString() );
 33
 34      Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 35      ArrayDescriptor descriptor =
 36         ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( p_in.getSQLTypeName(), conn );
 37
 38      p_out[0] = new ARRAY( descriptor, conn, values );
 39
 40  }
 41
 42  public static void
 43  pass_date_array( oracle.sql.ARRAY p_in, oracle.sql.ARRAY[] p_out )
 44  throws SQLException
 45  {
 46      show_array_info( p_in );
 47      java.sql.Timestamp[] values = (Timestamp[])p_in.getArray();
 48
 49      for( int i = 0; i < p_in.length(); i++ )
 50          System.out.println( "p_in["+i+"] = " + values[i].toString() );
 51
 52      Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 53      ArrayDescriptor descriptor =
 54         ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( p_in.getSQLTypeName(), conn );
 55
 56      p_out[0] = new ARRAY( descriptor, conn, values );
 57
 58  }
 59
 60  public static void
 61  pass_str_array( oracle.sql.ARRAY p_in, oracle.sql.ARRAY[] p_out )
 62  throws java.sql.SQLException,IOException
 63  {
 64      show_array_info( p_in );
 65      String[] values = (String[])p_in.getArray();
 66
 67      for( int i = 0; i < p_in.length(); i++ )
 68          System.out.println( "p_in["+i+"] = " + values[i] );
 69
 70      Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 71      ArrayDescriptor descriptor =
 72         ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( p_in.getSQLTypeName(), conn );
 73
 74      p_out[0] = new ARRAY( descriptor, conn, values );
 75
 76  }
 77
 78  }
 79  /

Java created.

SQL> set serveroutput on size 1000000
SQL> exec dbms_java.set_output( 1000000 )

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2      l_in strArray := strArray();
  3      l_out strArray := strArray();
  4  begin
  5      for i in 1 .. 5 loop
  6          l_in.extend;
  7          l_in(i) := 'Element ' || i;
  8      end loop;
  9
 10      demo_passing_pkg.pass( l_in, l_out );
 11      for i in 1 .. l_out.count loop
 12          dbms_output.put_line( 'l_out(' || i || ') = ' || l_out(i) );
 13      end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
Array is of type      OPS$TKYTE.STRARRAY
Array is of type code 12
Array is of length    5
p_in[0] = Element 1
p_in[1] = Element 2
p_in[2] = Element 3
p_in[3] = Element 4
p_in[4] = Element 5
l_out(1) = Element 1
l_out(2) = Element 2
l_out(3) = Element 3
l_out(4) = Element 4
l_out(5) = Element 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: This is not a good answer format. If the link is ever broken, the answer becomes useless to anybody that happens across it in the future.

Comment: Thats funny! because the link to this POST might be broken before the one I posted. But I have "Quoted" the content anyways. And to your point, this applies to "ALL Answers in Stack Overflow" that contains a link.

Comment: It's usually better to have some content along with the link then if it does get broken, the answer still helps. Links are great and v useful. In an ideal world answers would have info and links to further info.  Your tone suggests you took my comment badly, it wasn't intended that way at all. Just trying to make this Q&A as good as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

The way a nested table is recieved from an OUT parameter depends on how the table is nested consider a simple array type

object type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE HR.TNAME 
AS
OBJECT( NO1 NUMBER,
NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

table type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE HR.ITYPE_CUSTOM
IS TABLE OF tname;
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HR.p_schema_level_out(IN1 IN varchar2,p_det OUT itype_custom)
AS
lc_var itype_custom := itype_custom();
BEGIN
lc_var.extend;
lc_var(1) := TNAME(NO1 => 1,NAME => 'TRAIL1');
lc_var(1).no1 :=  1;
lc_var(1).name := 'qwe';
p_det:= lc_var;
END;
/
```

The above procedure which returns a custom array type can be handled by

```
try {

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        // -----------------------------------------------------
        // Call PL/SQL Procedure
        // -----------------------------------------------------

        String s1 = "begin p_schema_level_out(?,?); end;";
        cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall(s1);
        cstmt.setString(1, "something");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "ITYPE_CUSTOM");
        cstmt.execute();

        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cstmt.getObject(2)).getArray();
        for (Object tmp : data) {
            STRUCT row = (STRUCT) tmp;

            for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {
                System.out.println(attribute);

            }

            cstmt.close();
            stmt.close();

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

This works as a base on how you can recieve a table type i could still help you through if you can post your nested table type