# Oracle: Extract number from String

Tags: regex, oracle

I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968178/oracle-replacing-non-numeric-chars-in-a-string) and I'm wondering my output seems to be a little skewed.

From my understanding the `REGEXP_REPLACE` method, takes a string that you want to replace content with, followed by a pattern to match, then anything that does not match that pattern is replaced with the substitution param.

I've written the following function to extract distance from a text field, in which a spatial query will be performed on the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_distance
(
    p_search_string   VARCHAR2
) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_distance        VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN

    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(p_search_string), '(([0-9]{0,4}) ?MILES)', '') 
    INTO l_distance FROM SYS.DUAL;

    RETURN l_distance;
END extract_distance;
```

When I run this in a block to test:

```
DECLARE
    l_output VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
    l_output := extract_distance('Stores selling COD4 in 400 Miles');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_output);     
END;
```

I'd expect the output `400 miles` but in-fact I get `Stores selling COD4 in`.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but it looks like your code is removing the Regex pattern (i.e. Replace the pattern with '').      I think you need to negate the Regex, i.e  replace the part that is not the pattern with the empty string

Comment: Thanks Sparky, those were my thoughts too, however in the question I referenced the opposite behaviour is demonstrated. Maybe I should write a subsitution expression to override the first part of the string.

Comment: @Alex: In that question the regular expression *is* negated. `[^0-9]` doesn't match a digit, it matches a character that is not a digit. The `^` at the beginning of the set makes it a negative set.

Comment: @Guffa ah that is very interesting - Regex isnt my best area, so that would make sense

Comment: Performance wise, `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` approach would be efficient and less resource consuming than `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"REGEXP_REPLACE extends the functionality of the REPLACE function by letting you search a string for a regular expression pattern. By default, the function returns source_char with every occurrence of the regular expression pattern replaced with replace_string." from [Oracle docu](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302)

You could use, e.g.,
`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Stores selling COD4 in 400 Miles', '^.*?(\d+ ?MILES).*$', '\1', 1, 0, 'i') FROM DUAL;`

or alternatively
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Stores selling COD4 in 400 Miles', '(\d+ ?MILES)', 1, 1, 'i') FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use, regexp_substr which returns a substring that matches the regular expression.

[REGEX_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303)