# How to Extract Numeric Range from Text in SQL

Tags: regex, oracle

I am fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to extract some data from an ORACLE DB. My goal is to return rows where the query value lies in the range speicified by the "AA_SYNTAX" column in a table.

For example:

If the "AA_SYNTAX" column is 'p.G12_V14insR' and my search value is 13, I want to return that row. This column is organized as p.%number_%number%. So basically I want to return the two numerical values from this column and see if my query value is between them.

I have all the tables I need joined together and everything, just not sure how to construct a query like this. I know in regex I would do something like "\d+" but im not sure how to translate this into SQL.

Thanks

Comment: **Numeric range ! Ye be warned !!** because numeric range and regex don't go hand in hand.

Comment: I'd probably use regex_Replace as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968178/oracle-replacing-non-numeric-chars-in-a-string twice.  Once for before the _ and once for after the _ and then use that as your  where clause... `where AA_Syntax between RegEx1Eval and regEx2Eval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Oracle, you can [use Regular Expressions to extract a number from the string](https://community.oracle.com/thread/598281?tstart=0).

More specifically, I would look into [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm).

Using the date given in your example above, you could use:

```
with cte as
(
    select 'p.G12_V14insR' as AA_SYNTAX from dual
)

select 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(AA_SYNTAX,'p\.[[:alpha:]]+([[:digit:]]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as Bottom 
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(AA_SYNTAX,'\_[[:alpha:]]+([[:digit:]]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as Top 
from cte
```

I'm sure you could clean up the Regular Expression quite a bit, but, given this, you get the value of 14 for `Top` and 12 for `Bottom`.

Hope this helps move you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I understand how this is working, but how can I change the hard coded 'p.G12_V14insR' to the value of the column in the table. As in: "DB.TABLE.COLUMN as AA_SYNTAX from dual"

Comment: Exactly like you'd expect, it's a normal `select` statement. Simply select it out by your rules.

Comment: Just don't select from `cte` - I used that to simply create something to select from - Select from your table instead.... `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(AA_SYNTAX, ... FROM MyTable ....`