# How to do mathematical comparison to numeric strings in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column which stored numeric and string values. I want to filter those numeric values from that column. Suppose I need to get rows which less than 100.

## mytable

```
id     |    value
-------------------
1          aa
2          103
3          cc
4          90
5          88
```

suppose above in above table , 'value' column type is varchar.

I want to select value<100 rows.

my result set should be like as follows,

```
id     |    value
-------------------
4          90
5          88
```

Here is my imaginery query, But it doesn't

```
select * from mytable where TO_NUMBER(value)<100;
```

My question is deferenct than `TO_NUMBER("*")` case. Important thing is i want do a mathamatical comarison, which is i want to select `<100` numbers.

Comment: it should be like try parse . If that text value is a number. then it should check the numbers which is less than 100

Comment: You can always [remove non-numeric chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968178/oracle-replacing-non-numeric-chars-in-a-string), being careful to keep signs or decimal points when needed, but I guess it'll never perform nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values are decimals, then you can filter out incorrect values by:

```
 where case
        when regexp_like(value, '^\d+$') and to_number(value) < 100 then 1
        else 0
       end = 1
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30f32/9)