# SQL: Add some validation steps for phone number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a fairly simple bit of SQL code that's truncating three fields into one called "phone_number":

> Select pp.country_code_number||pp.area_code||pp.phone_number AS
>   phone_number

What I'd like to do is:

1. Remove any non numeric values in the data (some values have "07111-245 123" for example which I'd like to convert to "07111245123"
2. If country code = "44" then only return the pp.phone_number AS phone_number
   ELSE return "+" and pp.country_code_number||pp.area_code||pp.phone_number AS phone_number

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results *in a text table* is the preferred way to show data.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: So if I tried to insert "0sdg7esry1*^%H$1nN(#*12__4r5rtre12sdr3s", then "07111245123" would get inserted as a valid number rather than throwing some sort of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

Considering I didn't know the database, I implemented this in Oracle, PostgresSql and also MySQL.
These are the 3 databases that (in my experience) most commonly use `||` for concatenation (see: https://www.databasestar.com/sql-concatenate/ ).

**What you need are two things**:

- A string manipulation function to remove all non-numeric characters. In my example I used a stored procedure. Maybe a replace like Forpas example is good too (depending on your requirements ). In oracle you can also use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, see [Oracle: Replacing non-numeric chars in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968178/oracle-replacing-non-numeric-chars-in-a-string) .
- A Case expression or (decode in oracle also works) .

### Example (Oracle SQL)

```
WITH pp AS (

  select '30' as country_code_number, '1234' as area_code, '1234567-555' as phone_number from dual
  UNION
  select '44' as country_code_number, '1234' as area_code, '1234567-555' as phone_number from dual
)


SELECT CONCAT(CASE
                WHEN pp.country_code_number = 44 THEN ' '
                ELSE concat('+', pp.country_code_number)
                END, REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT (pp.area_code, pp.phone_number), '[^0-9]+', '')) AS phone_number
FROM pp;
```

### Example (Postgres)

```
select 

CONCAT(
CASE WHEN pp.country_code_number <> '44' then  concat('+',pp.country_code_number)
  ELSE ' ' 
  END
,

regexp_replace( concat (  pp.area_code , pp.phone_number ) , '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')
 )  as phone_number from

 pp;
```

Link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p6ziyWyWCGXTCiyiYSSyS8/2

### Example (MySQL)

```
  SELECT CONCAT(CASE
                  WHEN pp.country_code_number = 44 THEN " "
                  ELSE concat('+', pp.country_code_number)
              END, STRIP_NON_DIGIT(CONCAT (pp.area_code, pp.phone_number))) AS phone_number
FROM pp;
```

**DDL**

```
create table pp(

  country_code_number varchar(10),
  area_code varchar(10),
  phone_number varchar(20)
);

insert into pp values('30','210','123-456-789');
insert into pp values('44','210','123-456-789');

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS STRIP_NON_DIGIT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION STRIP_NON_DIGIT(input VARCHAR(255))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
      IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ) THEN
         SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
      END IF;
      SET iterator = iterator + 1;
   END WHILE;
   RETURN output;
END
$$
```

Link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p6ziyWyWCGXTCiyiYSSyS8/1

Comment: Thanks so much Menelaos, you were right, it was Oracle. I'm trying to build a report in Oracle BI using the HCM (Human Capital Management) database.
Thanks so much for a very thorough answer.

Comment: @Phil07952 can you accept the answer, and add the tag oracle to the question? Thanks!

Comment: What does this bit mean..
'[^0-9]+'
is is saying anything that is not a zero to nine?
What's the ^ do?
What's the + for?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `CASE` to check if the country code is 44 and the function `REPLACE()` (which works in most databases) to remove spaces and dashes:

```
select 
  replace(replace(case pp.country_code
    when '44' then pp.phone_number
    else '+' || pp.country_code_number || pp.area_code || pp.phone_number 
  end, ' ', ''), '-', '') AS phone_number
from phones pp
```

For Oracle and PostgreSQL you can use regexp_replace() to remove **all** non numeric chars
**PostgreSQL**:

```
select 
  case pp.country_code
    when '44' then regexp_replace(pp.phone_number, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')
    else '+' || regexp_replace(pp.country_code_number || pp.area_code || pp.phone_number, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g') 
  end AS phone_number
from phones pp
```

**Oracle**:

```
select 
  case pp.country_code
    when '44' then regexp_replace(pp.phone_number, '[^0-9]+', '')
    else '+' || regexp_replace(pp.country_code_number || pp.area_code || pp.phone_number, '[^0-9]+', '') 
  end AS phone_number
from phones pp
```

Comment: @forpas: this was actually really helpful and seems to have done the trick, I just had to re-order some of it to be:
'case when pp.country_code_number = '44'' then...
Thanks a lot :)